# How do I delete a relationship on Hyperledger Composer?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I'm running a simple test on Hyperledger composer where I have one asset, some users and two transactions:

1. assign an user to the asset, and
2. unassign the user from the asset.

The *assign* transaction is working fine. I create a relationship to the user and assign to the asset.

The problem is with the *unassign* transaction. How do I delete the relationship I've created?

Thanks

Renato

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, relationships are not enforced by Composer fyi (CouchDB is not a relational DB). See more here for a deeper explanation https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/3065#issuecomment-354953014

you would simply change it such that the asset (say `a1`) - is unassigned the current owner. To unassign, you can simply set the 'owner' field to 'none'. and the asset will be assigned an owner of "none" (it is unassigned). You can't set it to null.